# How to add Vhosts for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vhosts

I'm trying to have differents vhost for a rails application (7.0)

I added this lines in /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RailsEnv development
    ServerName bz.dev
    ServerAlias www.bz.dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/ben/code/multisite/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Add this line in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1               localhost
127.0.0.1 bz.dev
```

restart apache : sudo apachectl restart

sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder

When I going to bz.dev or [www.bz.dev](http://www.bz.dev) I get an url with https an this error message : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm on mac-os